# Would you use a transaction for this case?

Tags: mysql, select, transactions, insert

Based on the result of `SELECT COUNT` I assign the `userRole`, where 1 is the `foreign key of admin`, and 2 is the `foreign key of user` in `userRoles table`, and then I `insert` data to the users table. Would this be a good case to use a `transaction` since my `insert depends on the result of select` ?

```
try {

        // connect to the database
        require_once 'connect.php';
        // create a query to check if there are any records in the users table
        $querySelect = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(userId) FROM users");
        // run the query
        $querySelect->execute(); 
        // fetch the result as an array indexed by column number as returned in the result set and turn it into a string
        $sajResult = json_encode( $querySelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM) ); 
        $sajResult === '["0"]' ?  $sUserRole = 1 : $sUserRole = 2;
        // create another query to insert into users
        $queryInsert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( userName, firstName, lastName, password, image, 
        userRoles_roleId  ) VALUES ( :userName, :firstName, :lastName, :password, :image, :userRole )");
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':userName' , $sUserName );
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':firstName' , $sFirstName );
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':lastName' , $sLastName );
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':password' , $sPassword );
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':image' , $sImage );
        $queryInsert->bindParam( ':userRole' , $sUserRole );
        // run the query
        $bResult = $queryInsert->execute();
        // send response to the client if the query is true or false
        $sjResponse = $bResult ? '{"status":"ok"}' : '{"status":"error"}'; 
        echo $sjResponse; 


    } catch (Exception $e) {

        echo "ERROR";

    }
```

Comment: The problem with your question is that your code doesn't make much sense, or at least its function isn't explained very well. Why you do, what you do, will remain a mystery. You could easily include your SELECT test in your INSERT query, or even leave it out completely because `userId` will tell you how many users there were when a new user is inserted.

Comment: I updated my explanation, hope is understandable now what I want.

Comment: You use transactions when you want a sequence of queries to be all done in one go, and all succeed or not, without any other queries changing the data in between. Since you use two queries it is possible that two separate threads both execute the first query before they execute the second one. So, yes, if you leave your code like this, and first users are made frequently (?!?), you could use transactions. A better solution would be to rewrite the code and use only one query.

Comment: could you show me with code how would you use only one query  for this, please ?

Comment: I assume your 'userId` is an auto-incrementing index, starting at 1? In that case you can use `userId = 1` to test whether or not it is the first user. It makes perfect sense, and there's no need for the `userRole` column. Since I don't know your table definition, or why you do this, this is all I can say.